# Webscraping in VBA where some HTML information has no way to refer to it

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have this VBA script scraping from this URL https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/devices/10806378034350

I want the LOT,SERIAL, and EXPIRATION information which in the below pic, has a "Yes" or "No" inside the HTML.

How do I return just that Yes or No information?

[image: HTML SNIP]

```
Sub GetInnerInformation(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
    Dim HTMLResult As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLResults As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer

    Set HTMLResults = HTMLPage.getElementsByClassName("device-attribute")

    For Each HTMLResult In HTMLResults
        If (HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Lot*") = True Then
            Debug.Print HTMLResult.innerText, HTMLResult.outerText, HTMLResult.innerHTML
        End If
    Next HTMLResult

End Sub
```

In my Immediate Window I get:

```
Lot or Batch Number:        Lot or Batch Number:        Lot or Batch Number:
```

So no reference to the Yes or No that is in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML Parser:**

You could use a css [attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target the `span` with [?] that is just before the `div` of interest. Then climb up to shared parent with `parentElement`, and move to the `div` of interest with `NextSibling`. You can then use `getElementsByTagName` to grab the `labels` nodes, and loop that nodeList to write out required info. To get the values associated with labels, you again need to use `NextSibling` to handle the `br` children within the parent `div`.

I use xmlhttp to make the request which is faster than opening a browser.

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub WriteOutYesNos()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/devices/10806378034350", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim nodes As Object, i As Long

    Set nodes = html.querySelector("[title*='A production identifier (PI) is a variable']").parentElement.NextSibling.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")

    For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 3
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = nodes(i).innerText
            .Cells(i + 1, 2) = nodes(i).NextSibling.NodeValue
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**JSON Parser:**

Data is also available as json which means you can use a json parser to handle. I use jsonconverter.bas as the json parser to handle response. Download raw code from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called `JsonConverter` . You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. Remove the top `Attribute` line from the copied code.

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub WriteOutYesNos()
    Dim json As Object, ws As Worksheet, results(), i As Long, s As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    results = Array("lotBatch", "serialNumber", "manufacturingDate")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/devices/10806378034350.json", False
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With

    With ws
        For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = results(i)
            .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = IIf(json(results(i)), "Yes", "No")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**XML Parser:**

Results also come as xml which you can parse with xml parser provided you handle the default namespace appropriately:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub WriteOutYesNos()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, ws As Worksheet, results(), i As Long

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    results = Array("lotBatch", "serialNumber", "manufacturingDate")

    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:i='http://www.fda.gov/cdrh/gudid'"
        .async = False

        If Not .Load("https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/devices/10806378034350.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With ws
        For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = results(i)
            .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = IIf(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//i:" & results(i)).Text, "Yes", "No")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So I'm implementing the XML parser method and I'm getting an error automation error on the _.send line_ <br/>
`Sub XMLV3InnerInformation(URL As String, SearchInput As String, Manuf As String)
    Dim InnerHTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
    Application.Wait ("0:00:01")
    XMLPage.send
    Set InnerHTMLDoc = Nothing
    
    InnerHTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    XMLV3GetInnerInformation InnerHTMLDoc, SearchInput, Manuf
End Sub`
What's up with that?  Can't seem to find anything on here too.

Comment: No, instead I'm using xmlhttp60 and I see that DOMDocument has better error handling than xmlhttp60 in terms of waiting for the entire document to load.  On the plus side, I found the problem was happening do to me meeting a certain request threshold set by the website.  So again, I hardcoded *sigh* a fix that which I will improve upon with the DOMDocument methods.  The current fix is every 30 records I plug in I'm having wait 4 seconds and then proceed  (anymore than 30 I get too close to that threshold).  I'm also in a bit of a time crunch and IE I calculated would take days to finish.

Comment: Sounds like you got it sorted glad the approach helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Tinkered around and found it.  I had to hardcode the results a little but here is what I got.  Let me know if you've found a more elegant answer!

```
   Sub GetInnerInformation(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
        Dim HTMLResult As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim HTMLResults As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer
        Dim Lot As Boolean
        Dim Serial As Boolean
        Dim Expiration As Boolean

        Set HTMLResults = HTMLPage.getElementsByClassName("expandable-device-content")

        For Each HTMLResult In HTMLResults
            If (HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Lot or Batch Number*") = True Then
                Debug.Print HTMLResult.innerText

                If HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Lot or Batch Number: Yes*" Then
                    Lot = True
                End If

                If HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Lot or Batch Number: No*" Then
                    Lot = False
                End If

                If HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Serial Number: Yes*" Then
                    Serial = True
                End If

                If HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Serial Number: No*" Then
                    Serial = False
                End If

                If HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Expiration Date: Yes*" Then
                    Serial = True
                End If

                If HTMLResult.innerText Like "*Expiration Date: No*" Then
                    Serial = False
                End If

                Debug.Print Lot, Serial, Expiration
            End If
        Next HTMLResult

    End Sub
```